# crontab wp-cron.php on multisite path-based network: one for each path? Or just one for the root?

Tags: wp-cron, cron

I have a single wordpress with multisite config enabled:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
```

I want disable internal cron in wp-config.php with:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

My multisite installation is a path-based network, eg.:

```
http://www.foo.com/bar/
http://www.foo.com/baz/
http://www.foo.com/foo/
```

In my `crontab -e` I have:

```
*/10 * * * * curl -A "crontab" -X POST "http://www.foo.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=`date +\%s`" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

My two questions are:

1. I have todo a single cron for each path, eg:

```
*/10 * * * * curl -A "crontab" -X POST "http://www.foo.com/bar/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=`date +\%s`" > /dev/null 2>&1
*/10 * * * * curl -A "crontab" -X POST "http://www.foo.com/baz/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=`date +\%s`" > /dev/null 2>&1
*/10 * * * * curl -A "crontab" -X POST "http://www.foo.com/foo/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=`date +\%s`" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

or all they need is just one to the root eg.:

```
*/10 * * * * curl -A "crontab" -X POST "http://www.foo.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=`date +\%s`" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

2. I see in the apache access.log, wordpress cron uses POST method. Is important to use POST or I can use GET?

Comment: How many sites do you have? And yes, you need to hit each sites cron but you don't want to add the doing_wp_cron params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Q1 - One for each path / site. Each site has its own cron (jobs) internally. So, it is possible to fine-tune the frequency. For example, a low-traffic site may not have lots of cron jobs. So, the cron could be executed less frequently than a site that requires frequent updates.

For Q2 - You may use GET method. Also, instead of `cron` command, we may use a simple `wget` too. The query string "doing_wp_cron" is optional. A simple way to trigger WPCron is...

```
wget http://example.com/wp-cron.php
```

You may know about how everything fits together in [the official developer documentation for WP Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/).

Comment: Can you explain a little bit please?

Comment: `?doing_wp_cron=date +\%s` is useless because i have varnish cache and unique uri is essential!